# SQL multiple exclusive like

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to exclude selected rows based on the first letter of a column. I.e All rows that columns 'col' do not starts with Y, A or B.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tbl 
 WHERE col NOT LIKE 'Y%' 
   AND col NOT LIKE 'A%' 
   AND col NOT LIKE 'B%'
```

I've tried some variations such as using OR in place of AND or something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE col NOT IN ('Y%', 'A%', 'B%')
```

None of them give me the expected results,

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I've found that I am using MS-Access SQL which differs from MySQL. The `%` wildcard doesn't work for MS Access

It was just a mispelling issue. So the corrected version of this SQL is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE col NOT LIKE 'Y*' 
AND col NOT LIKE 'A*' 
AND col NOT LIKE 'B*'
```

Best regards,

Comment: Ah OK, the correct answer then is: "Don't use Access for anything, ever" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first example should work - can you post an example of what's wrong with the results?  The second example obviously won't work.

Most databases also support filtering by regular expressions, you may want to take a look at that.